# What might cause a memory error in haystack search when tried in python flask application?

Tags: python, elasticsearch, flask, haystack

I have indexed around 1000 document in elastic search. When I try to query with haystack search it returns files as output but after continuously using for 5 times memory error occurs. and the execution of program stops. I have attached the code that have used here.

```py
document_store = ElasticsearchDocumentStore(host="localhost", username="", password="", index="document")

json_object = open("doc_json_file.json")
data_json = json.load(json_object)
json_object.close()
document_store.write_documents(data_json)

retriever = TfidfRetriever(document_store=document_store)

reader = FARMReader(model_name_or_path="deepset/roberta-base-squad2", use_gpu=True)

pipe = ExtractiveQAPipeline(reader, retriever)

prediction = pipe.run(query=str(query), params={"Retriever": {"top_k": 20}, "Reader": {"top_k": 20}})

return prediction
```

Filename and file content are stored in a json file. Below one is the error log

```
OSError: [WinError 1455] The paging file is too small for this operation to complete
from .netcdf import netcdf_file, netcdf_variable
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 724, in exec_module
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 818, in get_code
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 917, in get_data
MemoryError
from pandas._libs.interval import Interval
ImportError: DLL load failed: The paging file is too small for this operation to complete.
```

Comment: Could you, please, share a more complete version of the code that would show how you use the code in flask? Can it be that you re-create the document store and upload the documents on each API call?

Answer (score 1):

If you're using `ElasticsearchDocumentStore`, better use `BM25Retriever` instead. `TfidfRetriever` is a simpler version that does not require an inverted index database like `Elasticsearch`.

As a downside it has to keep any index data in memory which can cause very high memory pressure. `BM25Retriever` in combination with `ElasticsearchDocumentStore` uses almost the same (but slightly superior) retrieval model and won't have that issue.